# Leaflet Angular component inside DivIcon

Tags: angular, leaflet

DivIcon is taking a html: string parameter, I currently concat a lot of html as string in order to render a divIcon that display different informations refreshing with a 3 second polling from an api.

I need to add more informations/styles and my strings's concatenation start to get really big and hard to css properly. I want to change it to a cleaner way.

1: I cant find any workaround in order to use a component into a DivIcon.

2: I managed to extract the innerHTML of an angular component but when I add dynamic @input(), the HTML extracted does not contain any dynamic data, it just extracts the basic template. ( Using ComponentFactory and ComponentRef.createComponent() )

3: The last option I am going to try is to instantiate hidden components and then getDocumentById it and extract the pure HTML from it.

https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#divicon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I solved it this with the option 1, I found a workaround.

I had the option 3 working (instantiate hidden components and extract the pure HTML from it) but then I figured out that Marker has a getElement() method that I could use, which allow me to get his HTMLElement in the DOM.

So I bypassed DivIcon, I just dynamicly instantiated my components and appended it into my marker HTMLElement, this is working fine, no need to worry about DivIcon anymore.

```
  constructor(
      private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
      private rendererFactory: RendererFactory2,
  ) {
      this.renderer = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
  }

    public appendPopupComponentRef(bus: BusDetails,
                               externalConfig: ExternalConfig,
                               el: HTMLElement,
                               vwcRef: ViewContainerRef): void {
    const factory: ComponentFactory<BusCardComponent> = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(BusCardComponent);
    const componentRef = vwcRef.createComponent(factory);

    // Custom it using his @Input()
    componentRef.instance.busDetails = bus;
    componentRef.instance.externalConfig = externalConfig;

    // Render popupComponent HTML inside the DOM's marker HTMLElement
    this.renderer.appendChild(el, componentRef.location.nativeElement);
}
```

Where el is my marker.getElement(); (You need the marker to be inside a layer in order to have his HTMLElement defined)

Where vwcRef is the root viewContainer.

you need `constructor(public viewRef: ViewContainerRef) {}` in your AppComponent

and this:

```
constructor(private appRef: ApplicationRef) {
    this.vwcRef = (appRef.components[0].instance as AppComponent).viewRef;
}
```